# Update instance and flavor

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

How can I update `flavor` and `image` of an instance? It is not possible with [this](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#update-server) api.

As another question, how can I update `ram`, `disk` and `vcpu` of the flavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize a server (change its flavor), use both the [resize](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#resize-server-resize-action) and the [resize confirm](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/#confirm-resized-server-confirmresize-action) APIs. See also [CLI instructions](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/resize.html).

To change the image, you need to [rebuild](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=resize-server-resize-action-detail,rebuild-server-rebuild-action-detail#rebuild-server-rebuild-action) the instance.

You can't update a flavor (except for its description), but it should not be too hard to create a new one that suits your needs. You can delete the old flavor, even if there are still instances that were launched with it. Flavors only affect instances at launch time; once they are running, whatever happens to the flavor is of no importance. See [flavor APIs](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=resize-server-resize-action-detail#flavors).